# Choosing an answer amongst too many different good answers

Tags: discussion

Recently I asked [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-important-is-knowing-how-to-program-for-tcs) on the main site.

In every answer I received there was something that I found interesting and bringing something to the question.

How should I answer this question, the possibilities that I though of:

- Making myself an answer which takes every things that I found helpful from every answers, citing the person that gave the answer (I could make this answer community wiki since it is an answer from everyone and not from me)
- Editing one of the already existing answers to add everything useful
- Choosing one of the answers as the main answer (least satisfying solution imho)
- Not choosing a right answer at all
- Other ideas?

Comment: Best way to chose an answer is to write a blog post for the cstheory blog summarizing the opinions of everyone about programming and TCS. :P

Comment: @Artem: Upvoted! :-)

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev good idea, I did not know anyone could write a post!

Comment: Please do write a blog post. that's a fantastic idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Dave that turning an answer into a summary of other answers is not good, and that it is not necessary to accept a single answer.  However, if you can write a good summary of the answers (as a blog post as Artem suggested, or as an answer), I think that that is also great.

Comment: That's indeed a great idea, I will definitely do this sometime next week (or at least as soon as I can)!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is any need to make an answer that summaries the other answers. Certainly editing one of the existing answers would not be good, as it will change the original author's intentions (unless the answer was CW). Not choosing a right answer is probably best, or selecting the one with the most votes.

Comment: Ok then I will stick with choosing no answer, maybe editing the question to explain why I did not chose an answer.

Comment: Problem with not accepting anything is that SE uses acceptance rate as some kind of quality measure for askers. We are not too concerned about it here (currently), but on others sites people are reluctant to answer people with low acceptance rates.